# Unable to Click via xpath,classname,location or index

Tags: webview, appium

I am working to automate an android app which have some screen of `webview` too. I am unable to click the right element through `xpath` class, with index or even with giving name text.

[image: screenshot]

If you see these screenshots it is visible that when I inspect element i get link to somewhere else. i tried using `getlocation` and then pass it for click but it also getting me wrong click.

I tried `touchaction` class methods but they are not working. My code get pass through appium but the methods tap or press nothing.

I tried this way too but no luck.

```
WebElement Quiz1 = (new WebDriverWait(driver , 20))
 .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Die Wish App')]")));
Quiz1.click();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also how can I use `webview` rather than `webelement`? and which one is preferable?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the element which you have highlighted in the screenshot.Below is the locator to identify that element

```
By.accessibilityId("Die Wish App")
```